# How do I implement the Clone Message Attack Protection feature of PokeIn?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pokein

I've tried to use the *Reverse AJAX and WebSocket Library*, [PokeIn](http://www.pokein.com/)

I want to send private message with this library and I found on PokeIn website the feature *Clone Message Attack Protection*.

How can I implement this feature? How can use the PokeIn security features?

Comment: Do you have code that you have tried? The site has extensive [documentation](http://www.pokein.com/Help/Documentation.aspx), so presume you have started and got stuck?

Comment: I read the documentation but I haven't found how I can implement "Clone Message Attack Protection". I've tried the samples on pokein website.

Comment: @Scott Can you help me with this implementation?

Comment: I haven't used PokeIn. You're best bet is wait for a response from the discussion boards on their website, as it is listed as their support channel for programming issues within their community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a feature works for all apps. It protects third parties cloning messages for other users or the same one. You shouldn't mix 'clone message protection' to 'protecting clone chat messages' as long as the sender client credential matches, PokeIn doesn't care about the details of the message. This one is something you need to cover up for your app.